# How to read data from SensorTag CC3200STK

Tags: c, linux, perl, sensors, texas-instruments

I just bought SensorTag CC3200STK. I want to read it's data on raspberry pi using wifi. I searched a lot on the web and forums but I could not find anything. Basically I want to read it's sensors data and display it on a webpage. I have all necessary things required to build a webpage and everything. I am only facing a huge problem on how to get data from SensorTag and store it.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru513a/swru513a.pdf), you need to connect your SensorTag to your access point. After successful connection, The SensorTag will start sending sensor data to predefined cloud url by using MQTT protocol. You can view the sensor data in your browser by visiting cloud url address.